# GPUImage:how to save imageView with subview

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I use the code from github named DLCImagePickerController.the sample just tell me how to use filter and then save,now i create a subImageView on the imageView to display the frame(just some pictures),when i want to save,i don't know how to save

Comment: You're going to need to provide a lot more detail than "it has problem" if we're going to have any chance of helping you here. What is the code you use to set up your views? Are you rendering to a GPUImageView and overlaying something on that? How is this all set up?

Comment: I use the code from github named DLCImagePickerController.the sample just tell me how to use filter and then save,now i create a subImageView on the imageView to display the frame(just some pictures),when i want to save,i don't know how to save

Comment: I haven't used the DLCImagePickerController code at all, so I can't comment on that. Are you trying to place an border around your image by overlaying another image? If so, look into the blend filters for how to do this.